# WebDriver exception

Tags: selenium2, webdriver, fitnesse, exception

I am using Fitnesse in order to define some selenium tests.
We got all of them running under CHROME but under FIREFOX some
exceptions are arising.
For running the tests I am using the external chrome webdriver.
That is, I am using selenium-server 2.7.0 and starting it in the following way:

```
D:\projects\dev\jdk\1.6\bin\java -jar ./selenium-server-standalone-2.7.0.jar - Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=c:\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe -Dfile.encoding=UTF8

__EXCEPTION__:org.openqa.selenium.InvalidElementStateException: Cannot perform native interaction: Could not load native events component.; duration or timeout: 2.05 seconds
Build info: version: '2.7.0', revision: '13926', time: '2011-09-23 13:24:59'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.6.0_16'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver; duration or timeout: 2.06 seconds
Build info: version: '2.7.0', revision: '13926', time: '2011-09-23 15:09:51'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.6.0_16'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:147)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:113)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:397)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ExecuteMethod.execute(ExecuteMethod.java:47)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteMouse.mouseMove(RemoteMouse.java:89)
at org.openqa.selenium.interactions.MoveMouseAction.perform(MoveMouseAction.java:37)
at org.openqa.selenium.interactions.CompositeAction.perform(CompositeAction.java:32)
at com.bmw.next.selenium2.util.MouseUtil.moveToElement(MouseUtil.java:22)
    ....
```

That is, an exception *InvalidElementStateException* has been thrown and I do not understand what is wrong.
The code is the same for Firefox and Chrome.
Anybody has experienced this behavior?

Any hint would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this happen with every Firefox mouse interaction, or only sometimes?

Comment: What version of Firefox are you running?  I had a similar issue running an older version of Firefox that was not supported, and you may run into problems with newer versions of Firefox that haven't been tested yet.

Comment: The last one. 7.0.1

Comment: it might also be helpful if you give us the code it threw the exception for.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that your element is not present.  the Click() method using the Firefox driver doesn't work like ClickAndWait in the Selenium IDE.  You must explicitly do an implicit wait before you click on something.  My guess is that you had 2 clicks right in a row, and it's failing on the second click because that element doesn't exist yet, because the first click submitted a form or something.

Call this method before the line of code that's failing.  You'll need to find the Java implementation of this C# code, but I think it might solve your issue.

```
public static IWebElement FindElement(this IWebDriver driver, By by, int timeoutInSeconds)
{
    if (timeoutInSeconds > 0)
    {
        var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeoutInSeconds));
        return wait.Until(drv => drv.FindElement(by));
    }
    return driver.FindElement(by);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also follow this procedure.
First, copy your web-element in to a variable of type web-element:

```
webelement elem=driver.findElement(By.id("elementid"));
```

Now make the action by

```
elem.click();
```

When DOM element changes, the `id` will not be same as the stack, so when a click action given after the element identification it will again check for the same element again.

This procedure can be used for possible exception like `staleelementexception` or `elementnotfound`.